# Vue typescript example

Tags: typescript, vue.js, requirejs

I'm trying to create a HelloWorld app with Vue and typescript

index.html

```
<script data-main="app.js" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>

<div id="app">{{text}}</div>
```

app.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'

var app = new Vue({
    el:"#app"
    ,data: {
        text: "hello there"
    }
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-example"
  ,"autohor": "nagyzsolthun"
  ,"dependencies": {
    "vue": "latest"
  }
  ,"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "latest"
    ,"requirejs": "latest"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
    ,"module": "amd"
    ,"moduleResolution": "node"
    ,"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    ,"experimentalDecorators": true
    ,"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]
  }
}
```

When opening index-html (after compiling app.ts) I see the following error:

```
GET file:///home/zsolt/prog/vue-boilerplate/vue.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

How can I make a working Vue app with typescript?

Comment: the `data-main` attribute should point to a file that contains, configuration for RequireJS. Something like `requirejs({ paths: { 'vue': 'node_modules/vue-boilerplate/vue.js' } })` this is just an example (I have not used requirejs in little while, but that is the basic idea.

Comment: I wouldn't create this from scratch. Use a boilerplate instead e.g. [vue-webpack-typescript](https://github.com/ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript) is a good choice because you can install it with vue-cli.

Comment: I would recommend using the new vue-cli.  As of v3, you can choose to use typescript! No more complex configuring or boilerplate needed. Check out the [Vue CLI 3 Documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need vue-class-component and vue-property-decorator. Just use an up-to-date babel boilerplate with webpack4 and preconfigured vue-typescript like [Darvin HTML Webpack Boilerplate](https://darvin.dev)

```
<script lang="ts">
  import {Component, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import { ... } from '@js/models/models.d.ts';

  @Component
  export default class myNewClass extends Vue {
    @Prop() someVar1: string;

    myVar: myErrorMsg | null = null;

    mounted() {
      ...
    }

    method1() {
      ...
    }
  }
</script>
```